# Getting increasingly slow to write into textbox using textBox_TextChanged event and if statement together.

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox, textbox

I am making a dictionary using C# and Windows forms. In my dictionary I have a `textBox` where the user can search for a word to get the meaning. I also have some options in a `comboBox` where the user can choose a language to see the meaning for that language. Because I am making the dictionary for different languages.

My code looks like:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string word = textBox1.Text;

    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Database\condrokothadb.sdf;Password=000;");

    //in combobox there are 2 option(language)
    //if select one language(option) from combobox
    if(mood=="bangla") 
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter b = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT english,bangla FROM dic WHERE (bangla like '" + word + "%')", con);
        DataTable tt = new DataTable();
        b.Fill(tt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tt;
    }
    else   //by default english language is selected 
    {
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();              
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter b = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT english,bangla FROM dic WHERE (english like '" + word + "%')", con))
            {
                DataTable tt = new DataTable();
                b.Fill(tt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = tt;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString() == "Bangla")
    {
        mood = "bangla";
    }
    else if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
    {
        mood = "english";
    }
}
```

My problem is that when a user want to write something into the textbox it is getting so much slower to write. How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting data from server in every text changed you can get all data in grid at once and then filter them with dataview.

```
// to get data in grid
CustomList<wordlistDAO> WordList = null;
WordList = WordListBLL.GetAllWord();
GridWord.DataSource = WordList ;

// create word datatable for filtering 
DataTable dtWord = null;
dtWord = new DataTable();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn colu in GridWord.Columns)
                        dtWord .Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colu.HeaderText));
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridWord.Rows)
{
   DataRow dr = dtWord.NewRow();
   foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        dr[row.Cells.IndexOf(cell)] = cell.Value;
        dtWord .Rows.Add(dr);
}

//create data view
DataView wordlistview = new DataView();
wordlistview  = new DataView(dtWord);

// filter dataview and show in grid

if (cboLanguage.Text == "Bangla")
 {
   wordlistview.RowFilter = "bangla LIKE '" + txtSearchValue.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "%'";
 }
else
{
 wordlistview.RowFilter = "english LIKE '" + txtSearchValue.Text.Trim().ToUpper() +    "%'";
}   
 GridWord.DataSource = wordlistview;
```

Comment: I cant understand how to save all the data into a datatable and make a dataview.Would you please give me details?

Comment: i assume u have english and bangla 2 columns in your dataview. in that case u can filter your dataview depending on the selected language from combobox(cboLanguage). i have edited my answer. please check last lines of code. hope it will work for you.

Comment: you do not need datalist. seems you got your data in your datatable (tt). Now u can follow from `create data view` step.

Comment: getting data all at once is a very bad idea and practice, you'll bore the end-user out with slow perfomance

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question and here is how I would solve it.

I added a timer that starts to count as you type the first character into your textBox, and for every character you add the timer resets. The application wont execute the part where you search through the database untill the timer reaches a set number of ticks.

Make sure you add a `timer` and a `backgroundWorker` into the form. Create the events through the properties window and add this code:

```
int timerTicks;
int waitUntill = 10; //10 = 1 second. Change this to decide how long the application will wait.

string mood;
string word;
string langConnection;

DataTable tt;
SqlCeConnection con;
SqlCeDataAdapter b;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!timer1.Enabled)
        timer1.Start();
    //Reset the timer when a character is entered in textBox1.
    timerTicks = 0;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerTicks++;

    if (timerTicks > waitUntill && !backgroundWorker1.IsBusy && comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        //Stop the timer and begin the search in a background thread.
        timer1.Stop();
        word = textBox1.Text;
        mood = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    tt = new DataTable();
    con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Database\condrokothadb.sdf;Password=000;");

    langConnection = String.Format("SELECT english,bangla FROM dic WHERE ({0} like '{1}%')", mood, word);

    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        b = new SqlCeDataAdapter(langConnection, con);
        b.Fill(tt);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tt;
}
```

Note that you don't need the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event for this to work.

**EDIT:**

To make the actual search run faster you would have to open the connection at startup and keep it open throughout the entirety of the execution, like other answers suggest as well. You should be able to figure that out for yourself though.

Comment: It is little bit faster but not so what i expect...Please give a another way that will be more faster.

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = tt; in this line 'tt' cant be accessible.

Comment: Initialize `DataTable tt` at the start. Like I did with `timerTicks` and `waitUntill` in my first answer.

Comment: It didnt work properly. shows an error like "This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently".

Comment: @DarkenShooter Okay, I can fix that but before I update my answer I have two questions about the code. What are the possible values of mood, is it just "english" and "bangla"? Why do you have a using block and a `con.Open()` on the english part and not on the bangla part in the if statement?

Comment: possible value for mood is "english" and "bangla"...Con.open is used both for bangla and english.I mistakenly did that before.

Comment: @DarkenShooter Oh! another thing, why do you use sqlDataAdapter for english and sqlCeDataAdapter for bangla? I took the liberty to clean up the code a bit and I'm asking to make sure I don't change anything important.

Comment: @DarkenShooter Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: In this line "langConnection = String.Format("SELECT english,bangla FROM dic WHERE ({0} like '{1}%')", mood, word)" I cant understand why you use {0} for mood here.Shouldnt it be english.Because i want to show data where english like word from database.

Comment: @DarkenShooter Ok I have another idea. I don't have time right now though, I'll come back later...

Comment: @DarkenShooter The idea was basicly to open the connection earlier in the code to prevent it from having to be opened multiple times. It's easier for _you_ to experiment with that though, since you have the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that, every time you press a key in the textbox, you are creating a database connection and querying the database.  This is very inefficient!  Also, because your Bangla code doesn't dispose of the connection, you may be keeping a lot of objects referenced that don't need to be, so you may find performance is degrading over time.

One basic suggestion would be to use a single connection instead of opening new connections for each keypress.  This will reduce somewhat the time taken for the query.  Realistically though, I suspect that you want to load the full content of the data at once, and run your query in-memory.  This will give you much better speed.

Running your query on a background thread will help maintain the responsiveness of your UI, but will potentially end up with lots of queries running at once trying to catch up with the user's typing.

A better solution is to consider running an "idle-timer," and only starting the query when the user has stopped typing for a short amount of time.  I'd recommend still using a background thread for this.  You won't query the database for every keypress, and you won't affect the responsiveness of the UI.

Comment: "I suspect that you want to load the full content of the data at once, and run your query in-memory. This will give you much better speed" How can i do that??? @Dan Puzey

Answer (score 1):

Doing a search in the database on any keystroke is a bad practice. As you already experienced, it makes the UI very slow. A better option would be to do the search in a background thread, and also not for every keystroke. You can wait some time (0.5 seconds for example) before doing the search. If the user pressed another key in the meantime, expand the wait again to another 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @DarkenShooter Sorry, I'm busy now. I'll implement a working solution when got some free time.

Answer (score 1):

Delay could be due to large amount of data in the database and you're calling database for every text changed event. 
What I would suggest is to get all the data into DataView and keep filtering and binding the grid with results from view. That way you can minimise the number of times database is called.

Comment: How can i search data from dataview and how to bind the result data into dataGridView?? @Prabhu